# Convert XML into SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Here is my XML Format:

```
<ROOT>
<Orders>
    <OrderID>423</OrderID>
    <ProductID>54</ProductID>
    <ProductID>23</ProductID>
</Orders>
<Orders>
    <OrderID>523</OrderID>
    <ProductID>5</ProductID>
    <ProductID>26</ProductID>
</Orders>
```

I want to have my output in the below format

```
OrderID         ProductID   
423             54  
423             23
523             5
523             26
```

I found ways that help me read attribute from XML and convert it to SQL table. But didn't find ways or solution for my XML input.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's stopping you from adapting it to work with _your_ XML format?

Comment: Hi jordan28, is this issue solved or do you need further help?

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, that was really helpful. Yes the issue is solved. Cheers!

Comment: I upvoted your solution but it showed a message. I was not aware of the tick sign. Thanks again for making me aware :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<ROOT>
<Orders>
    <OrderID>423</OrderID>
    <ProductID>54</ProductID>
    <ProductID>23</ProductID>
</Orders>
<Orders>
    <OrderID>523</OrderID>
    <ProductID>5</ProductID>
    <ProductID>26</ProductID>
</Orders>
</ROOT>';

SELECT  Ord.value('OrderID[1]','int') AS OrderID
       ,Prod.value('.','int') AS ProductID
FROM @xml.nodes('/ROOT/Orders') AS A(Ord)
CROSS APPLY A.Ord.nodes('ProductID') AS B(Prod)
```

As your *leading* value is the ProductID you need a `nodes()`-call for this. It was possible to use only one `.nodes('/ROOT/Orders/ProductID')` and find the corresponding OrderID with a backward move:

```
SELECT  Prod.value('(../OrderID)[1]','int') AS OrderID
       ,Prod.value('.','int') AS ProductID
FROM @xml.nodes('/ROOT/Orders/ProductID') AS  B(Prod)
```

But it is cleaner and better performing to move down the tree step by step...